# Android Resource Qualifiers -sw#dp vs -w#dp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resource-qualifiers

Say I'm developing a different layout for devices with screen size equal to or greater than 600dp.
I want to use the post android 3.2 resource qualifiers. I created a folder named `layout-sw600dp` and put my layout there, but at the same time I could have created a folder named `layout-w600dp` and put the layout xml file there. 
I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between `-sw600dp` and `-w600dp`? After all they are both meant to use the layout for device of width >=  600dp.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`sw` is "*smallest* width". It doesn't change if the device is rotated.

`w`, on the other hand, is available (i.e. *current*) width.

See [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources):

> **smallestWidth - `sw<N>dp`** - The smallestWidth is a fixed screen size characteristic of the device;
>   the device's smallestWidth does not change when the screen's
>   orientation changes.
>
> **Available width -   `w<N>dp`** -  This configuration value will change when the orientation changes between landscape and portrait to match
>   the current actual width.

Example. Say that you have a device that is 600dp x 400dp.

- If you have a w600dp resource, it will be used in landscape, but not in portrait.
- If you have a sw600dp resource, it will not be used for any orientation (smallest is 400).

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But I still don't get it. what do u mean by width is not changed if deviced is rotated. the width is changed

Comment: @user1409534 Yes, but not the _smallest_ width. Edited answer with example, hope it's helpful.

Comment: ~"**but not in portrait**".  Actually, both portrait and landscape will be used for calculating width in **w<N>dp**